# Using operating system fonts inside a flash application without embedding it

Tags: flash, flex4, font-face

I'm starting to localize my flash application.
I'm trying to see if there is a way to rollback on default operating system fonts for languages like japanese so I don't have to embed them.
So far I didn't find anything online.
I'm currently using css to define the font family like :

```
@font-face
{
   fontFamily: "Tuffy Regular";
   src:url("/assets/fonts/Tuffy-Regular.ttf");
   embedAsCFF: true;
}
```

Any advice on this ?

Thanks

Olivier

Answer (score 2):

In AS3 you can style text 2 ways, with TextFormat, and with StyleSheet.
You want to use StyleSheet:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

And you want to use the fontFamily attribute to specify the font families you want.

Here is a working example:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.StyleSheet;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

public class Main extends Sprite {

    public function Main() {
        var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();

        var heading:Object = new Object();
        heading.fontWeight = "bold";
        heading.color = "#FF0000";
        heading.fontFamily = "Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";

        var body:Object = new Object();
        body.fontStyle = "italic";
        body.fontFamily = "Courier New, Courier, monospace";



        style.setStyle(".heading", heading);
        style.setStyle("body", body);
        //style.setStyle("fontFamily", 

        var label:TextField = new TextField();
        label.styleSheet = style;
        label.htmlText = "<body><span class='heading'>Hello </span>World...</body>";
        addChild(label);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using Flash Builder and the goal is not to have no font but to be able to specify a list of font priority for flash player to look into the operating system fonts to find one the user have.

Comment: Edited my post to answer how to do it according to your comment request.

Comment: Thanks, it helps! I still have to figure out what is the best way for me to deal with different *.css files and how to change my mxml components, but making progress.

Comment: I think stylesheet is still the right direction. Flash can even parse a stylesheet: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html#parseCSS()
However the flash implementation of CSS is a small subset of any version of CSS. (By the way, would you mind clicking Accept if this answered your question?)